# $ionicLoading templateUrl not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

> app.js

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'services'])

.run(function ($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });

    $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function () {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            templateUrl: 'templates/loading.html', animation: 'fade-in', showBackdrop: true, maxWidth: 200, showDelay: 0
        });
    });

    $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });     
})
```

> And my loading.html is present in templates folder and this app.js is in js folder.

Also I experimented many thing like put loading.html file along with index.html, given templateUrl : '../templates/loading.html'.

Comment: Hi, I can't find animation,maxWidth, showDealy option in http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/

Comment: yes these properties are supportable. I don't think these are creating problems. @Hasta Pasta

Comment: can you add code for templates/loading.html file ?